# Burninate [unresponsive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unresponsive) tag (x172) seems wholly unnecessary.

- Used in a wide variety of contexts for all kinds of issues and languages.
- Has no description, and it's both broad and vague.
- No one can be an expert at unresponsiveness.
- It is not useful.

Can we burninate it?

Comment: *No one can be an expert at unresponsiveness.* Really? You should see the servers I work with.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: You mean the coworkers, don't you?

Comment: @Robert, well, in my experience, that's not where the bottleneck lies ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi in my experience, that's where ALL the bottlenecks lie :-)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ^ that or the administration

Comment: completed task :)

Answer (score 25):

What is unresponsive? This tag says nothing about the question. The whole purpose of tags is so that experts can easily find questions about the area in which they are most confident. It is impossible to truly be an expert at unresponsiveness. In fact, following this logic, verbs should generally not be used as tags.

Let it burn.

Comment: I agree. [tag:unresponsive] is redundant; let’s burninate it.

Comment: I was hoping a 2k+ user would have done this so I didn't look like a rep farmer, but as nobody seems to have done it so far I've started to do it. Down to 81 remaining, but there's at least one that I don't know how to deal with (very unclear question with [unresponsive] as its only tag).

Comment: it's not just about rep farming.  When a sub-2k user makes these updates, it bumps the questions up to the front, and increments them one more step toward community-wiki status.  Don't be surprised if you're nipped for it.

Comment: That seems like a strange thing for it to do. I won't lose any sleep over lost reputation if the powers that be decide to remove it however. I didn't realise it was going to bump the questions up though :(

Comment: @NewAlexandria: There's no auto-CW since a long time...

Comment: @Deduplicator Good to know.  Around 2014-06 I was moderated for it, which would mean that a significant slice of reviewers bore this outdated conception — enough to add it to the comments. The annals of SE.